# How can I tell if two outlets are on different phases?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I have a house that had a 240v stove in it, and then was replaced with a gas stove, all before I bought it. There are two regular 120v outlets under it, that are both 120v, and the gas stove is plugged into one for the igniter. No 240v.

I want to put an induction stove in, which requires 240v. The last owner said he thinks the 240v outlet that powered the electric stove was just split into two 120v outlets, and I should be able to make a 240v outlet back out of them. Says it was a long time ago and not that sure.

How can I go about finding out if they are indeed on different phases so I would know a 240v outlet can easily be made there, before I go and buy a induction stove?

I have a basic multimeter if that is helpul.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there are two separate duplex receptacles there now

- Set your multimeter to measure AC volts.
- Carefully stick one probe in the ungrounded (hot) side of one receptacle (the smaller slot).
- Carefully stick the other probe in the ungrounded (hot) side of the other receptacle.

If you measure 240 volts (or there abouts), then the receptacles are on separate legs. If you measure 0 volts, they're on the same leg.

Keep in mind that the breaker and/or conductors that supply the circuit, could have been changed at the same time the receptacle was changed.  So you'll have to make sure the breaker and conductors are sized properly for the appliance you intend to install.

***WARNING:*** If you don't feel comfortable jamming metal objects into an electrical outlet, you might want to contact a local licensed Electrician.

Comment: If you read 0 volts across the two hots, it could just be that they only used one hot and the neutral to connect the outlet and left the other hot disconnected. So you could still be able to use the existing wiring (assuming it's sized appropriately).

Comment: If the breaker for that circuit was changed from its 240 volt breaker to two 120 volt breakers, you'll have to change them back to one 240 volt breaker so that both legs trip when one does.

Comment: Thanks. It came out as 120V, but I opend up the box and there was a wire capped wire, and using that as one of them shows 240V, so I should be good. Thanks!

Comment: **To the next guy who reads this answer:** Do not hold the two live leads in separate hands. Always hold both leads with a single hand, so that any potential that goes through your body will stay in the hand and not cross your chest. If the two outlets are far apart in this case, then have separate (non-touching) people hold each lead.